# Preventing fake forms from sending data to server

Tags: php, forms, ip

Suppose that I have a comments form, and I want to prevent bad users from copying the form html source code , with the action attribute to use it elsewhere outside my website.

What I have to do?

I got a simple idea, But I don't know if it's working or not (even I don't know what php methods to use)

The idea is to add a variable $ip in the page, this $ip is the php file (and form) location (maybe using $_SERVER['PHP_INFO'] or other)... then sending this variable to the add.php file with a POST method but without displaying in the html code source.

in add.php , the server will check if the ip of the page is equal to the ip adress of the server or not , then it will decide wether to add comment or kill the operation.

I hope discuss about this subject

thank you in advance

Comment: you cannot hide html from users, users are evil!

Comment: no, not html, but a variable $ip working in the server, to get the location of the form (the server where the hacker has put the fake form)

Comment: in facebook for example, I can copy the login form, and put it elsewhere in my server, then login from the fake facebook form

I think this is a bug

Comment: So , if the bug is corrected, the facebook server will get the myserver's (my form's) location (ip) , then compare it with facebook server's Ip , then decide whether to login or not

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do the following:

1. Generate a unique hash.
2. Store that hash in the session.
3. Implement a hidden field, with the hash as value.
4. Check the hash on the submitted page.

Comment: the form will send the hash to the add.php page, then it will compare it with the hash in the session, that's right?? but the problem is when the bad user copies the form from the source code he will copy also the hash with it, then send it

Comment: He will have to copy it every time he'd like to submit it, which would be about as efficient as not copying it at all.

Comment: That's why you generate a new, unique hash every time the page is loaded, at your server, and store it in session. An attacker can't modify your stored session data...

Comment: But I know that there are non-lazy attackers hhhh, they can copy it everytime if they know that it's changeable

Comment: Can't we use only the session to send the hash??? without puting in in a hidden form?

Comment: If they would need to copy it every request, they might aswell fill it in on your website.

Answer (score 5):

This is called Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF). Rails already got this built in. I don't know what PHP-framework you're using, but I do know CakePHP also got it built in.

If you don't use a PHP-framework, or if the framework you are using doesn't got this functionality, you can just Google to `CSRF protection PHP` and click the 2nd link (http://codeutopia.net/blog/2008/10/16/how-to-csrf-protect-all-your-forms/).

Comment: Thank you friend ... even facebook has this bug :loool

Answer (score 4):

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Contains the URL that the form is submitted from. If the URL isn't your site then you can expect it to be from your server as long as they are not attempting to spoof headers.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

A better option is to generate a unique key in a hidden input. Something along the lines of:

```
<?php
$my_salt = 'fs gadfgasfhg usfaghsa gosg435435874542584 htrwhgsfgbsfgu';
$hash = sha1($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . date('d/m/y') . $my_salt);
?>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $hash; ?>" />
```

Then when the form is submitted recreate the hash and compare it to the one that is posted back with the form. Obviously the hash that I am generating above is only going to provide you minimal security and you really should make it more secure.

Comment: Won't work. It's pretty easy to crack this (a bot can just add the referer-header).

Comment: You're sorta missing the point here though. If he can spoof the referer, then he can defeat CSRF tokens nearly as easily. The value in checking the referer header is that, as a general rule, it should not be possible to forge from web content alone.

Comment: I have clearly stated it can be manipulated in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @SimoTAQI Please review the documentation for `$_SERVER`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php and you will see it is `The IP address from which the user is viewing the current page.`. Anyway it was just an example...

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a hidden input or use session variable to perform CSRF Protection.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds pretty difficult to me this. There's certainly nothing you can do to completely hide the mechanism from the user, since you would have to send the client some kind of data to identify them when they load the page, and there is nothing to stop the user from viewing that data (even if it is an encrypted version of the data), however you do it.

The only thing I can think of is to use sessions, and add some sort of unique digest to a hidden form element or a cookie when you generate the page, store it in $_SESSION and check that the value you get beck when the form is submitted is the same as the value to sent in the first place.